# How to loop through JSON objects?

Tags: java, android, json, api

```
{
   "stocks":{
      "0":{
         "name":"Torn City Stock Exchange",
         "acronym":"TCSE",
         "director":"None",
         "current_price":10018.747,
         "market_cap":0,
         "total_shares":0,
         "available_shares":0,
         "forecast":"Average",
         "demand":"High"
      },
      "1":{
         "name":"Torn City and Shanghai Banking Corporation",
         "acronym":"TSBC",
         "director":"Mr. Gareth Davies",
         "current_price":529.863,
         "market_cap":4300246833486,
         "total_shares":8115771121,
         "available_shares":0,
         "forecast":"Average",
         "demand":"High",
         "benefit":{
            "requirement":4000000,
            "description":"Entitled to receive occasional dividends"
         }
      },
      "2":{
         "name":"Torn City Investment Banking",
         "acronym":"TCB",
         "director":"Mr. Paul Davies",
         "current_price":502.819,
         "market_cap":5771083717274,
         "total_shares":11477457529,
         "available_shares":1539811799,
         "forecast":"Average",
         "demand":"Average",
         "benefit":{
            "requirement":1500000,
            "description":"Entitled to receive improved interest rates"
         }
      }
}
```

How can I loop through all the items with key-value pairs? I want to extract name, acronym , total shares, available_shares and demand. Please help! I'm creating a android app using java and I'm stuck here.

Comment: Can't you get a JSON array for 'stocks' from the server side / source? That would make your life a lot easier iterating through it.

Comment: Letme try it @SiddharthKamaria

Answer (score 5):

IMO this is not a proper way of having a list of objects in a JSON.
If you can, you should change this to

```
{
  "stocks": [
    {
      "name": "Torn City Stock Exchange",
      "acronym": "TCSE",
      "director": "None",
      "current_price": 10018.747,
      "market_cap": 0,
      "total_shares": 0,
      "available_shares": 0,
      "forecast": "Average",
      "demand": "High"
    },
    {
      "name": "Torn City and Shanghai Banking Corporation",
      "acronym": "TSBC",
      "director": "Mr. Gareth Davies",
      "current_price": 529.863,
      "market_cap": 4300246833486,
      "total_shares": 8115771121,
      "available_shares": 0,
      "forecast": "Average",
      "demand": "High",
      "benefit": {
        "requirement": 4000000,
        "description": "Entitled to receive occasional dividends"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Torn City Investment Banking",
      "acronym": "TCB",
      "director": "Mr. Paul Davies",
      "current_price": 502.819,
      "market_cap": 5771083717274,
      "total_shares": 11477457529,
      "available_shares": 1539811799,
      "forecast": "Average",
      "demand": "Average",
      "benefit": {
        "requirement": 1500000,
        "description": "Entitled to receive improved interest rates"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

An ideal way would be to have a mapping class in Java and capture the JSON as List, then you can easily iterate.

```
private String json = "your json object here";

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

List<MappingClass> stocks = objectMapper.readValue(jsonArray, new 
                            TypeReference<List<MappingClass>>(){});

  for (MappingClass stock : stocks) {
      stock.getName();
      // other fields
  }
```

Try having a look over [The Jackson Library](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) and ObjectMapper for reference.

Comment: @AbhishekUpadhyay I am glad it worked for you. You can mark my answer accepted so the question gets closed.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably want to use a well known JSON library such as GSON or JsonPullParser. GSON can deserialize your JSON into a Map that contains objects that you will have to define. So it will be something like a Map<Integer, Bank>.
Your Bank class would look something like this:

```
public class Bank {
   String acronym;
   String name;
   //...
   Benefit benefit;
}
```

and then, if you use GSON, your parsing code will look something like this:

```
Map<Integer,Bank> bankMap;

Gson gson = new Gson();

Type type = TypeToken.getParameterized(Map.class, Integer.class, Bank.class).getType();
//result is a String that has your JSON!
bankMap = gson.fromJson(result, type);
for (Bank bank : bankMap.values()) {
   System.out.println("Bank name:" + bank.name);
   //...
}
```

The documentation for GSON is comprehensive and well written. It can be found here:
https://github.com/google/gson

I hope what I wrote helps you! Good luck and please let me know how things went.